# How to remove indicator in ngb-carousel with html tables instead of images

Tags: angular, html-table, carousel

Currently working on an angular 5 project that needs to put the rendered html table inside on a carousel. I tried using the ngb-carousel and it rendered the expected output but I need to remove the indicator at the bottom as shown on the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use CSS:

In your template:

```
<ngb-carousel class="no-indicators">
```

In your global CSS style sheet:

```
.no-indicators .carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3vcqs?file=app/carousel-basic.html)

Comment: Thanks, it works! :) One last quesiton, is it possible to disable to auto slide of ngb-carousel?

Comment: Sure. Set the interval to any value <= 0. https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.spec.ts#L272